# Objects react different to different types of radiation

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, thermal-radiation

I am a bit confused about the different types of radiation and how objects react to it. In class, the professor showed us a cube with white, black and reflecting sides (the Leslie cube). Inside the cube, there's a glowing lamp. When the sides of the cube are measured. There can be concluded that the black sides have on average the same temperature as the white sides. Hence, they emit the same IR-radiation. The reflecting sides have the lowest temperature.

Later in the same class, the professor shows us the following experiment:
[image]

There's a lightbulb (that's emitting light in the visible spectrum), two coloured thermometers (in respectively black and white) and a non-coloured thermometer. The black thermometer increases the most in temperature, the white thermometer increases in temperature the second most and the non-coloured thermometer increases a bit. In conclusion, in the visible spectrum is it dependent from the colour how much heat is emitted and absorbed.

Black colour: more absorption and emission

White colour: less absorption and emission

In conclusion, the emissivity of an object is dependent on the golf length of the radiation.

In our book, we saw this example with a blackbird plane. The plane gets heated by air resistance.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

However, there seems to be a contradiction between the example and the experiments. My question is:

Which one of the two is wrong? The lessons and the example seem to contradict each other.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.